# gmaps4rails update from 1.4.8 to 1.5.6 map does not display

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, gmaps4rails

I have had a rails 3.1 app running gmaps4rails 1.4.2 (and 1.4.8) for some time.  All has been working great.

Recently I tried to update gmaps4rails to 1.5.6.  After I do that update, the map no longer displays (no controls either).  I verified the @json is populated and appears correct.  I have also inspected the code when running and I am seeing this error:

**Uncaught Type Error: Object  has no method 'triggerOldOnload'**

This error occurs around this line:

```
Gmaps.oldOnload = window.onload;
window.onload = function() { Gmaps.triggerOldOnload(); Gmaps.loadMaps(); };
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'triggerOldOnload'
</script>
```

This problem is repeatable:  If I use bundler to go back to 1.4.8 the maps start working again, and if I update to 1.5.6 the map again disappears.

I love gmaps4rails!  If there is anything I can do to help you troubleshoot this problem, please let me know!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: did you run the rake task to get the freshest js?

Comment: Derp!  Nope I had just done a bundle update... And there are your instructions as plain as day:  "and be sure to copy the fresh assets when you upgrade the gem".  Thanks that did the trick!!

Comment: If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's annoying, I'm well aware, but you need to run the rake gem command to get the freshest assets.

```
rails generate gmaps4rails:install
```

I should update this...